# How to delete about 1,000 Gmail labels, not one at a time

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, delete

I need to start over with Gmail labels, is there a way to blow away all of them at once? I have way too many.

Comment: We are looking for practical, detailed questions about using web applications, not for simple requests asking for "how to" / tutorials. See [tour] and [ask]. Questions looking for a software recommendation might be asked in [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- create a new sheet: **https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create**
- install this addon: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/labels-manager-for-gmail/nebfojpnebfgnifdcenfcafkddfgbcdc?utm_source=permalink)**
- go to **Add-ons**
- select **Label Manager for Gmail**
- select **Setup Wizard**
- select **Create Label Sheets**
- wait
- go to **Add-ons**
- select **Label Manager for Gmail**
- select **Export Labels** (2x)
- wait
- click on **3. Export Labels** sheet
- copy labels you want to delete into **4. Delete Labels** sheet (into column **A**)
- go to **Add-ons**
- select **Label Manager for Gmail**
- click on **Delete Labels**
- wait on status
- done

[image: 0]

- video tutorial: **https://youtu.be/FWLouKFqpVY?t=25**

Comment: this addon is unavailable now. Any alternatives?