# How to move Gmail labels from one account to another

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, automation

Is there any way to transfer all the Gmail labels from one account to another.

Importing filters are easily possible by exporting and importing. Importing filters also creates the labels they are associated with. But importing filters doesn't create the labels they aren't associated with.

I want all the labels to be transferred to a new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done by following steps from **[this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/129064/186471)**.  You will need to import/scrape your labels from your first account, then switch to the second account and paste your labels to create all of them at once.